# Is there a way in waterline / nodejs to not return all fields? Or should I filter the json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, waterline

I am writing a little REST API with nodejs, express and waterline. If I retrieve a record and return it with `res.json(post);` this contains data I don't want to display in the API (like IDs, associations, etc.).

Is there a way to tell waterline which fields to retrieve? If not, what would be the best way to whitelist what will be sent out?

Comment: I think you're looking for [toObject()/toJSON()](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/instance-class-methods.md#toobjecttojson) methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### waterline

From waterline perspective, you can use `select` when you retrieve the records, example from the [docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/5cc4b64207a8cb8e81c53358c7d6024e26e02147/queries/query-language.md#select):

```
// Returns only the field name
Model.find({ where: { age: { '<': 30 } }, select: ['name'] })
```

You can also implement [toJSON](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/instance-class-methods.md#toobjecttojson) as suggested by @Rodrigo.

### node.js / lodash

From node.js side of things you can also use lodash's `pick()`, example from the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#pick):

```
var object = { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 };
_.pick(object, 'user');
// → { 'user': 'fred' }
```